# 1 sec connecting to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7

I'm running php 5.3.10 on Windows IIS 7.5 And the mysql version is 5.1.56

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
```

And this line *consistently* takes 1 full second.

Where would I start trouble shooting?

Comment: Is the MySQL server on a different physical host ? If so, are you passing the host's FQDN (DNS associated identifier) to mysql_connect or its IP address ?

Comment: Antivirus looking at connection?

Comment: It's on the same LAN but on a physical server. And we do NOT pass the IP, we pass the FQDN.

Comment: Next step then would be to test how long it takes to resolve DNS from the web server to the database server, and if it makes a difference to pass the IP

Answer (score 2):

I just changed the DNS name to IP and boom! It's lightning fast now!